# Filtering multiple values (more than two) using XML filter for WFS

Tags: wfs, xml

I'm having a problem using WFS XML filter. I'm trying to read only six features from entire dataset and I get the following error:
[![Error][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6nyx.png

I wrote query in SQL and need to convert it to XML:

```
"SAV_ID" IN (21,23,25,55,56,88)
```

Interestingly when I'm quering only two of thoses features, I get no errors. XML filter (working one) for two features is:

```
    <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Or>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>21</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>23</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Or>
</ogc:Filter>
```

I tried the following variants (for more than 2 features):

(1) (gives error)

```
    <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Or>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>21</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>23</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>55</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Or>
</ogc:Filter>
```

(2) (gives error)

```
    <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Or>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>21</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>23</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Or>
    <ogc:Or>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>55</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Or>
</ogc:Filter>
```

(3)

```
    <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:Function name "in">
            <ogc:PropertyName>SAV_ID</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>21</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>23</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>55</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function name "in">
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
```

Last one (3) downloads all the features. Any help on that?